# Sorted array: how to get position before and after using name? as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have been working on a project and Stack Overflow has helped me with a few problems so far, so I am very thankful!

My question is this:

I have an array like this:

```
var records:Object = {};

var arr:Array = [
records["nh"] = { medinc:66303, statename:"New Hampshire"},
records["ct"] = { medinc:65958, statename:"Connecticut"},
records["nj"] = { medinc:65173, statename:"New Jersey"},
records["md"] = { medinc:64596, statename:"Maryland"},
```

etc... for all 50 states. And then I have the array sorted reverse numerically (descending) like this:

```
arr.sortOn("medinc", Array.NUMERIC);
arr.reverse();
```

Can I call the name of the record (i.e.  "nj" for new jersey) and then get the value from the numeric position above and below the record in the array?

Basically, medinc is medium income of US states, and I am trying to show a ranking system... a user would click Texas for example, and it would show the medinc value for Texas, along with the state the ranks one position below and the state that ranks one position above in the array.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is this timeline code or in a class (.as) file?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the object, you can use the array.indexOf().

```
var index:int = records.indexOf(records["nj"]);

var above:Object;
var below:Object;

if(index + 1 < records.length){ //make sure your not already at the top
   above = records[index+1];
}

if(index > 0){  //make sure your not already at the bottom
   below = records[index-1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will return the position number. I am looking to return the value defined in "medinc" of the particular position rather than the position number itself.

Comment: then just do `below.medinc` or `above.medinc`.  index is the position number, `above` and `below` are the actual objects of the next highest and lowest objects in your array

Comment: keeping in mind that below and above will be null if not applicable (the current item is the top or bottom of the array)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer based on my understanding of your data.

```
var index:int = arr.indexOf(records["nh"]);
```

That will get you the index of the record that was clicked on and then for find the ones below and above just:

```
var clickedRecord:Object = arr[index]
var higherRecord:Object = arr[index++]
var lowerRecord:Object = arr[index--]
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I believe this will return the position numbers? I am looking to return the "medinc" value defined in the array for the position that is selected. For example, if New Hampshire "nh" is selected, it would return the "medinc" of the state that is in the position of index++ and index-- rather than the position number itself

Comment: See, the first line actually returns you the number, and then you use that number to retrieve "medinc" value from the previous and next element of "arr", via `var medincUpper:int=arr[index-1]['medinc'];` and similarly for next. But be sure to check array boundaries, otherwise your program will throw exceptions if there's no previous or next element. And Haronious, you did wrond addressing higher record and lower record, in your code higherRecord will be equal to clickedRecord, and lowerRecord will actually be higherRecord due to behavior of index++ and index--, be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need records to be hash?

If no, you can simply move key to record field and change records to simple array:

```
var records: Array = new Array();
records.push({ short: "nh", medinc:66303, statename:"New Hampshire"}),
records.push({ short: "ct", medinc:65958, statename:"Connecticut"}),
....
```

This gives you opportunity to create class for State, change Array to Vector and make all of this type-safe, what is always good.

If you really need those keys, you can add objects like above (with "short" field) in the same way you are doing it now (maybe using some helper function which will help to avoid typing shortname twice, like addState(records, data) { records[data.short] = data }).

Finally, you can also keep those records in two objects (or an object and an array or whatever you need). This will not be expensive, if you will create state object once and keep references in array/object/vector. It would be nice idea if you need states sorted on different keys often.

Comment: This doesn't belong here since it's not an answer to the question but an efficiency/code sustainability suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a good way to have your data set up - too much typing (you are repeating "records", "medinc", "statename" over and over again, while you definitely could've avoided it, for example:

```
var records:Array = [];
var states:Array = ["nh", "ct", "nj" ... ];
var statenames:Array = ["New Hampshire", "Connecticut", "New Jersey" ... ];
var medincs:Array = [66303, 65958, 65173 ... ];
var hash:Object = { };

function addState(state:String, medinc:int, statename:String, hash:Object):Object
{
    return hash[state] = { medinc: medinc, statename: statename };
}

for (var i:int; i < 50; i++)
{
    records[i] = addState(states[i], medincs[i], statenames[i], hash);
}
```

While you have done it already the way you did, that's not essential, but this could've saved you some keystrokes, if you haven't...

Now, onto your search problem - first of all, true, it would be worth to sort the array before you search, but if you need to search an array by the value of the parameter it was sorted on, there is a better algorithm for that. That is, if given the data in your example, your specific task was to find out in what state the income is 65958, then, knowing that array is sorted on income you could employ [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Now, for the example with 50 states the difference will not be noticeable, unless you do it some hundreds of thousands times per second, but in general, the binary search would be the way to go.

If the article in Wiki looks too long to read ;) the idea behind the binary search is that at first you guess that the searched value is exactly in the middle of the array - you try that assumption and if you guessed correct, return the index you just found, else - you select the interval containing the searched value (either one half of the array remaining) and do so until you either find the value, or check the same index - which would mean that the value is not found). This reduces [asymptotic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_complexity) of the algorithm from O(n) to O(log n).

Now, if your goal was to find the correspondence between the income and the state, but it wasn't important how that scales with other states (i.e. the index in the array is not important), you could have another hash table, where the income would be the key, and the state information object would be the value, using my example above:

```
function addState(state:String, medinc:int, statename:String, 
    hash:Object, incomeHash:Object):Object
{
    return incomeHash[medinc] = 
        hash[state] = { medinc: medinc, statename: statename };
}
```

Then `incomeHash[medinc]` would give you the state by income in O(1) time.